# Set some text on label in "Left Call Out View" from array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a "Map View" in which i want to set some text on label in "Left Call Out View" from array. Text should set in "did select" delegate.
  how can i identify selected annotation? how can i set the text from array, because i don not know  index of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maintain tag for each annotation view in viewfor annotation method on didselect by using tag you can get indepath of array

Comment: but the tags of annotation view do not set in sequence , i mean tag of the annotation will set first,  which will appear first

Comment: sorry,i didn't get you please  explain once detailly

Comment: suppose tags of all annotations has been set then every thing is fine. After that if i changes the region of mapview to region where is no annotation, and again drags the mapview by finger to region where are some annotations, and view for annotation calls again then suppose secondly added annotation appears first then tags will shuffled and tag sets again.

Comment: then do one thing add tag to annotation at the time of adding Annotationview